# WordPress: How to Get the Link of the "Last Modified" Author

Tags: php, wordpress

## Context

For posts in WordPress, you can:

- Get the author **link** with [`the_author_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_link) or [`the_author_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_posts_link).
- Get the of "Last modified" author **name** with [`the_modified_author()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_author).

Which are great, but I'm looking for sort of a hybrid.

---

## Question

How do I get the **link** of the "Last modified" author? For example, this is what I would like to output:

`Last updated by John Doe on May 5, 2016.` (I've already got [the time and date part](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_time).)

However, this is all I can seem to manage to output:

`Last updated by John Doe on May 5, 2016.` (There's no link.)

### "Well, what type of link are you trying to get?"

I would like to get the link to posts by the person, so when you click on "John Doe", it would take you to the list of posts that John Doe has written.

To perhaps give better idea of what I was hoping for, I was expecting there to be a function with a name something along the lines of, "`the_modified_author_posts_link()`". Either that or for `the_modified_author()` to take arguments, but it doesn't.

---

## Attempts and Research

I thought, as an indirect way of going about it, maybe I could somehow get the ID of the last modified author, then pass that ID through [`the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) or some such function and get the link that way, but I can't find anything on how to obtain an ID for the modified author either.

I searched the WordPress Codex and support forums, Google and Stack Overflow for a while. All I managed to find is how to get the author, the last modified author, and other stuff I've already mentioned.

I tried looking in the WordPress Codex for [functions related to the_modified_author()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_author#Related) and things like that but found nothing that seemed explicitly helpful.

I'm quite certain this can be done and there's probably some really easy way to do it, but maybe I missed something. Thank you in advance for any help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there isn't a function that does that. That said, you could try something like this:

```
function the_modified_author_posts_url() {
    global $post;
    if ( $id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_edit_last', true ) ) {
        echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( $id ) );
    }
}
```

Then, in the loop:

```
Last updated by <a href="<?php the_modified_author_posts_url(); ?>">
<?php the_modified_author(); ?> </a> on <?php the_modified_date(); ?>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine. Thanks! What's the `'_edit_last'` thing about though? I can't seem to find much information on it.

Comment: `'_edit_last'` is the meta key for the post that stores the user who last edited a post.

[get_post_meta documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: I must mention that does not work for posts that are published with WordPress block editor (Gutenberg) due to this issue: [#31501](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/31501)